# Using the and operative for multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I am trying to receive a single true/false response for multiple comparisons of sma.  I am able to receive a return for all of them separately from my data set, however, I would like a single response.

It is currently as follows:

```
df['Criteria 1'] = df['50 sma'] > df['30 sma']
df['Criteria 2'] = df['30 sma'] > df['15 sma']
df['Criteria 3'] = df['15 sma'] > df['5 sma']

df
```

I have tried a number of variations using "and" with no success, such as:

```
df['Criteria 1'] = df['50 sma'] > df['30 sma'] and df['30 sma'] > df['15 sma'] and df['15 
sma'] > df['5 sma']

df
```

As I have little experience I am trying to keep the code very simple.  How can I use an "and" operator to provide a single response to all of the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `&` instead of `and`. Try this:

```
df['Criteria 1'] = df[(df['50 sma'] > df['30 sma']) &
                      (df['30 sma'] > df['15 sma']) &
                      (df['15 sma'] > df['5 sma'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Hamid.  I could not get it to run as expressed above, however, after taking out the brackets I was able to get a response.  Returned a response with the following expression

```
df['Criteria 1'] = (df['50 sma'] > df['30 sma']) & 
                   (df['30 sma'] > df['15 sma']) & 
                   (df['15 sma'] > df['5 sma'])
df
```